# how to store date default values to table.but it takes null values

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am fresher in Sql server 2008.
i create table as:

---

```
-- Table structure for [xyz]
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE [xyz]
GO
CREATE TABLE [xy] (
[abc] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()  NOT NULL
)
```

in inserted time date values as:2013-08-07 00:00:00.000
i want store time value as it is present time.

Comment: Did an application insert that value or was that the default value?

Comment: Something else must be setting that value.  I have used your CREATE statement and get the proper time value.  Please add your INSERT statement to your question as well.

Comment: why i get this time value...

Comment: Something else must be setting the value - `GETDATE()` will include the current server time.

Comment: i store default value from java code .....i got select GETDATE() query value is fine.

Comment: Can you share your Java code as the query which I have answered is running correctly for me!!! There must be a problem in your Java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the time stamp for current time for each inserted record.

```
DROP TABLE [xyz]
GO
CREATE TABLE [xy] (
[abc] DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT_NAME DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR myColumn
```

Comment: how to write constraint name at table create structure

Comment: Constraint_name like NOT NULL or Null or Unique or CHECK or
DEFAULT ....etc.... :)

Comment: @ Rahul Tripathi DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()  NOT NULL i written in create query

Comment: So what is the issue? I am not getting your point. If you have created the table you just have to alter it.

Comment: i create table fine....i am inserted time take default current date in this time in the date column store 2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 this.but i want to store 2013-08-07 07:11:11.201

Comment: This is strange that getdate() is returning  2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 instead of 2013-08-07 07:11:11.201. Are you sure you are running it correctly?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35288/discussion-between-suresh-manda-and-rahul-tripathi)

Comment: "i store the date value through java" then the default on the server has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is not including the date - the default value only applies when you do not specify a value - it does not "magically" add the time component to the date you pass in.  If you *want* to add the date you'll have to create an UPDATE/INSERT trigger to add the current time to the date that's pass in.

However, I would just update your Java code (if you can) to include the time.

Comment: i write trigger for mysql...but i did not understand how to write trigger for sqlserver...please tell that